# IHostedService - StopAsync vs Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

I am building an `IHostedService` implementation. My service does a few things, which should be dealt with when service gets terminated, like registering some event handlers to external service in `StartAsync()`.

Now I wonder, where should I actually deregister these handlers? Naturally I'd do it in `Dispose()`. However, what is `StopAsync()` for then?

In a Console App environment, I think it would work like this:

1. `StopAsync()` is called
2. `Dispose()` is called

I'd like my app to be well designed and to cover also other possible scenarios. In example, background services. I think in such scenarios there is an option to `StopAsync()` and then `StartAsync()` without `Dispose()` in between. Am I right?

Should I handle such situations, I mean, to check in `StartAsync()` if I am already registered somehow?

It's hard to find some best practices regarding generic host in .NET Core with console apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispose` is called when your object is ready to be collected by the garbage collector (broadly speaking).

It doesn't have much to do with hosted services, rather a generic interface in .NET. I'm not entirely sure if services can be stopped then started again. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) say the following.

> The hosted service is activated **once** at app startup and gracefully shut down at app shutdown. If an error is thrown during background task execution, Dispose should be called even if StopAsync isn't called.

So I recommend you register your handlers in `StartAsync` and deregister/cleanup on `StopAsync`.

If you have native resources (such as File Handles, Pipes, sockets), you should clean them up in `Dispose`. Do not expect StopAsync to be called. Your host may have failed to close services gracefully, but Dispose will likely be called if your service is "released" so you can still clean up and be a good citizen.

Comment: To be clear on the native resources - System.Net.Sockets.Socket, although it has a native socket is itself a managed class that implements IDisposable, so should be closed in StopAsync?

Comment: yea, you can do it at either, just that `StopAsync` may not be called, and services cannot be restarted, it is safer to do cleanup in both. i.e, cleanup on StopAsync, and also on Dispose, if StopAsync wasn't called. Make sure running both doesn't cause errors. Dispose WILL be called, where Stop MAY BE called.